# XSD: elements with same name in different files used together

Tags: xml, xsd

I have a set of XSD files each having the following structure:

message_i.xsd

```
<xs:complexType name="message_i">
    <!-- definition of message -->
</xs:complexType>

<xs:element name="document" type="message_i"></xs:element>
```

So each of the xsd-files contains an element called "document" of type that file defines. The xsd-files are being used by a webservice that receives messages of specific "document" types.

The man thing is that I need to have a bunch of elements "document" but of different types.

Now I want to combine several messages into one. I created the following code:

```
<!-- some data -->
<xs:element name="document1" type="message1">
<xs:element name="document4" type="message4">    
<xs:element name="document5" type="message5">
```

But I get the error stating that this document contains element that already exists in the target namespace. And that name is "document".

How can I create an element that contains different messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't see that without without defining each complex type in each xsd, but

Add a namespace to each xsd

e.g.

```
<xs:schema xmlns:DOC1="http://www.mySite.Com/DOC1" />
```

Then your complex type would be DOC1:message_i

so you could have,

```
<xs:element name="document1" type="DOC1:message_i">
<xs:element name="document4" type="DOC2:message_i">
<xs:element name="document5" type="DOC3:message_i">
```

Comment: Do i have to add targetNamespace to each XSD? After doing like you said i get an error stating that link to DOC1:message_1 is prohibited